# Databinding, Binding class can't find RealmObjects

Tags: android, realm, android-databinding

I was using databinding with realm objects and after updating android studio and gradle the auto generated Binding classes can't find the RealmDb classes or directory.
I tried removing the realm object out of the databinding but the project won't override the existing auto generated class and i keep getting the same error.

[image]

This is how i'm binding the data

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_article_info, container, false) as FragmentArticleInfoBinding
    val view = binding.root
    viewModel = ArticleInfoVM(arguments?.getInt(KEY_ARTICLE_ID)!!)
    binding.article = viewModel?.article.get()
    return view
}
```

Why isn't the project able to find the classes?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Android Studio has not found directories, if are there any error about different issues.

You can try to delete "RealmDB" package and clean All project then retry to insert emtyp RealmDB package. If are there any error, fix in order.